# Swift property - getter ivar

Tags: swift, getter

Is there an ivar property we should use in a Swift getter? My code is causing the getter to call the getter until the program crashes:

```
var document: UIDocument? {
    get {
        return self.document
    }
    set {
        self.document = newValue

        useDocument()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Swift properties do not have the concept of separate, underlying storage like they do in Objective-C. Instead, you'll need to create a second (private) property and use that as the storage:

```
private var _document: UIDocument?
var document: UIDocument? {
    get {
        return _document
    }
    set {
        _document = newValue
        useDocument()
    }
}
```

If all you're trying to do is call `useDocument()` after the `document` property is set, you can omit the getter, setter, and private property and instead just use `willSet` or `didSet`.

Comment: I've added a note to the answer that if your actual code is this simple, you can just use `willSet` or `didSet`.

Comment: I originally used `didSet` but I need `useDocument` to run before the property is initialised. (It’s set in the presenting VC `prepareForSegue`

Comment: `useDocument` is still not called when the property is initialised in the presenting VC’s `prepareForSegue`

Comment: There was a problem in my `prepareForSegue` code - thanks for your help :)

Comment: If `useDocument` does anything with you view controller's UI, the reason it's not working from `didSet` on initialization (from `prepareForSegue`) is that your VC's view isn't loaded yet. Check `self.document` in `viewDidLoad` and call `useDocument` there.

Answer (score 10):

If what you are trying to achieve is add some custom processing when the property is set, you don't need to define a separate backing data member and implement a computed property: you can use the `willSet` and `didSet` **property observers**, which are automatically invoked respectively *before* and *after* the property has been set.

In your specific case, this is how you should implement your property:

```
var document: UIDocument? {
    didSet {
        useDocument()
    }
}
```

Suggested reading: [Property Observers](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_378)

Answer (score 4):

In your code there is an infinite recursion situation: for example, `self.document` inside the getter keep calling the getter itself.

You need to explicitly define an ivar yourself. Here is a possible solution:

```
private var _document:UIDocument?

var document: UIDocument? {
    get {
        return self._document
    }
    set {
        self._document = newValue

        useDocument()
    }
}
```