# Swift: Conditionally Set Private Ivar

Tags: swift, properties

In Objective C, I can ask the question 'isEqual' and avoid setting the instance variable if it is already the same instance.

```
-(void)setManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
if (![_managedObjectContext isEqual:managedObjectContext]) {

    __weak NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = _managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator;

    // iCloud notification subscriptions
    NSNotificationCenter *dc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [dc addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(storesWillChange:)
               name:NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification
             object:psc];

    [dc addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(storesDidChange:)
               name:NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification
             object:psc];

    [dc addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges:)
               name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification
             object:psc];

    _managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
}}
```

Is this possible from within the setter of a var in swift?

Comment: One remark regarding your code `if (![_managedObjectContext isEqual:managedObjectContext]) {`. I believe you should only check pointer equality instead of object. Indeed `isEqual` will check pointer equality for you but direct pointer comparison will run faster: if (_managedObjectContext != managedObjectContext)

Comment: Ah yes, good point Max. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with one nuance: swift lacks of implicit ivars in Objective-c sense. You have to do ivar on your own. And use `===` operator to check pointer equality.

```
import Foundation

class Setter: NSObject {

    private var __property: NSObject!

    var property: NSObject!{
        get {
            return self.__property
        }
        set {
            if newValue === self.__property { return }
            self.__property = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Please check out this [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828987/swift-property-getter-ivar) for details regarding `ivar` concept in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

If you use == that checks whether the objects are equal and === checks whether two instances have the same reference i believe