# Warning: Attempting to access 'myProperty' within its own getter vs SwiftFormat

Tags: swift, getter

I have code like this:

```
@IBInspectable var myProperty: String? {
    set(newValue) {
        //logic for setter
    }
    get {
        return myProperty
    }
}
```

The above code generates a warning:

> Attempting to access 'myProperty' within its own getter. Access 'self'
>   explicitly to silence this warning.

So I fix the code as suggested:

```
@IBInspectable var myProperty: String? {
    set(newValue) {
        //logic for setter
    }
    get {
        return self.myProperty
    }
}
```

The problem would be solved but I am using [SwiftFormat](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwiftFormat) during the application build phase.
And SwiftFormat automatically removes the **self** keyword, treating it as unnecessary here.

I see two solutions:

1. Turn off the **redundantSelf** rule in SwiftFormat.
2. Modify (how?) the code to be acceptable for both the compiler and the SwiftFormat.

What would be the best choice for this?

Comment: Your getter recursively calls itself, so that is wrong anyway (leading to a stack overflow quickly) – with or without warning. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/24025340/1187415.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is incorrect in the first place. Adding `self` will not help.

What you have created is infinite recursion. When `myProperty`'s getter is called, you `return myProperty`, which calls the getter again. in the getter you return `myProperty` again and this calls the getter again. This will go on forever until the stack overflows.

If you just want a custom setter, you can try `willSet` or `didSet`.

```
var myProperty: String {
    willSet(newValue) {
        // do stuff
    }
}

// or

var myProperty: String {
    didSet(oldValue) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: What if need a custom getter?

Comment: @BrittoThomas then write a custom getter.

Comment: can please write syntax for that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148782/how-to-create-a-custom-getter-method-in-swift-4

Comment: Can you please check the above question?

Comment: @BrittoThomas, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25829062/3833666) might be cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I hit this same warning when attempting to write an Objective-C style property with a backing ivar:

```
var myProperty: String {
    guard let myProperty = _myProperty else {
        _myProperty = "some string"
        return myProperty // Attempting to access 'myProperty' within its own getter
    }
    return myProperty
}
var _myProperty: String? = nil
```

Expanding the error message in Xcode, however, shows that the warning has a hint on the second line:

```
// Attempting to access 'myProperty' within its own getter
// Access 'self' explicitly to silence this warning
```

Changing to `return self.myProperty` thus silences the warning in cases where the calls will not cause infinite recursion.