# How to create a custom getter method in Swift?

Tags: set, swift4, var, setter

I am trying to create a custom setter method for my property using the code below:

```
var myProperty: String {
    get {
        if CONDITION1 {
            return CONDITION1_STRING
        } else if CONDITION2 {
            return CONDITION2_STRING
        } else{
            return myProperty
        }
    }
    set {
        
    }
}
```

But this gives the warning:

> Attempting to access 'myProperty' within its own getter

Comment: you cannot refer the a computed property during computing it, that logically seems/feels/is a recursion; you may need to create a stored property (e.g. `fileprivate var myPrivateProperty: String = ""`) and you can return that rather than `return myPrivateProperty`, and in the setter you need to assign the new value to it, like e.g. `myPrivateProperty = newValue` and job's done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a backing ivar and add a custom setter:

```
private var _myProperty: String 
var myProperty: String {
    get {
        if CONDITION1 {
            return CONDITION1_STRING
        } else if CONDITION2 {
            return CONDITION2_STRING
        } else {
            return _myProperty
        }
    }
    set {
        _myProperty = newValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all quote from Apple Swift Documentation:

> **[Computed Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)**
>
> In addition to stored properties, classes, structures, and
> enumerations can define computed properties, which do not actually
> store a value. Instead, they provide a getter and an optional setter
> to retrieve and set other properties and values indirectly.

The first thing above quote suggesting is that, you can use custom getter and setter of property to get or set values of other property indirectly without exposing it or make it public for others.

If you try to access/get value of property within its own getter than again you are calling getter and loops go infinite. As we know allocation of all this calls are on stack, and stack has limited memory, so once calls stacked at full capacity then it can not handle any more calls and it crash with stackoverflow error.

So, never get or set property's value within its own getter and setter. They are here to provide access to other variables and properties.

Lets expand your code to use `myProperty` With custom getter. I am renaming it here it as `myName`.

```
private var firstName : String = ""
private var lastName : String = ""

var myName: String {
    get {
        if CONDITION1 {
            return firstName
        } else if CONDITION2 {
            return lastName
        } else {
            return firstName + lastName
        }
    }
}
```

Here I add two private property `firstName` and `lastName` but make it `private`. But I add another property `myName` which is public, so i implement custom getter to retrieve name of user based on condition and provide access of `firstName` and `lastName` indirectly.

By same way you can implement custom setter to set value of `firstName` and `lastName` of user.
But you can not make use of self within its own scope.